# yarn link error No registered package found called

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm developing an npm package for custom React Hooks. And using yarn for package management. The custom hooks are in the `src` directory, and to prevent posting the wrong code to npm, I've created a new `demo` folder locally at the same level as src.

To test my hooks code locally, I bundled my hooks and used `yarn link` to link it in my `demo` project smoothly as if I installed it from the registry. And next I run `yarn start` in my `demo` folder to run my test project. But it reminded me Invalid Hook Call Warning in the Chrome console.

After reading this [article](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react) I knew that it is because I used duplicate React, So I tried to this command: `yarn link ../node_modules/react` but it just told me

```
error No registered package found called "../node_modules/react".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link for documentation about this command.
```

But when I tried to use `npm link ../node_modules/react` there is no error reported. I can start my test project smoothly.

But here comes the problem: I am using yarn for package management and it has its own lock file `yarn.lock`. If I want to run my test project, I had to run `npm link ../node_modules/react`, this step will generate a npm lock file which is a Redundancy for me.

So how can I use `yarn link ../node_modules/react` instead of `npm link ../node_modules/react` to link a same version React?

Here is the [whole repository](https://github.com/liyiming22/react-countdown-hook)

Answer (score 2):

I will assume this question is still relevant because I stumbled upon it while looking for the answer myself. I managed to figure it out eventually.

The [yarn link docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/link/#toc-yarn-link-in-package-you-want-to-link) state the following:

> This command is run in the package folder you’d like to consume.

In order to create a link for React, you have to `cd ../node_modules/react` and then `yarn link` while in that directory. You can then use `yarn link react` from the other side to consume the linked package.

For the record, it doesn't look like it matters which side you create the link from (the library or the consumer) as long as the other side makes use of it.